# How to use cclive to stream video?

Tags: linux, video-streaming

There are a few tutorials explaining how to use cclive to stream video, however, they are a couple years old and cclive has changed recently. With a current version of cclive how do you stream the video you are downloading to a video player like vlc?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to watch it, you don't need to download the video, just do :

quvi "URL" --exec "vlc %u"